# Converting stored dates and times to user-frindly outputs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

So I am storing messages in a SQL table with type: timestamp default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which looks like this: 2014-11-11 11:43:23 in the database and when printed.

I am printing the time along with the messages, but am looking for a way to convert this to a more user-friendly format, i.e. something that is dynamic and says, "12:15" if it was written today or something like "Monday 12:15" if it were written on monday at 12:15.

As I have never done anything like this, I am wondering if there are snippets that handle this (I couldn't find any for my stored format), or will I need to start from scratch?

I am certainly open to storing the time differently if someone knows of a program for a specific stored format.

Anyway, Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) library, its an extension of PHP's DateTime class.
It has what you're looking for: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-humandiff

It will show relative time like "an hour ago" or "10 days ago", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('l H:i', strtotime('2014-11-11 11:43:23')); //Tuesday 11:43
```

pass a format in `date()` you will get your output

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to just store the data as a native data type (e.g. `timestap`, `datetime`), based in your DBMS.

If you decide to format your data in php you can format it by using php's `date()` function. It allows you to output formatted/human-readable datetime value from either date objects or string. For more info for available formats visit this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

I was interested by your question and managed to retrieve the result you were looking for :

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME,
    @day VARCHAR(100),
    @time VARCHAR(100)

SET @date = '2014-11-11 11:43:23'


SELECT @day = (
  DATENAME(dw, 
  CAST(DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(d, @date) AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(yy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR))
  )

SELECT @time = CAST(@date AS TIME)

PRINT @day + ' ' + LEFT(@time, CHARINDEX('.', @time)-1)
```

RESULT : 'Tuesday 11:43:23'

Please let me know if you need any clarity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code - It will displays as `Tuesday 11:43`

```
$date_time="2014-11-11 11:43:23";
$dte_new=date("l H:i", strtotime($date_time));
```

Use below code to display as `Tuesday 11:43 AM`

```
$date_time="2014-11-11 11:43:23";
$dte_new=date("l H:i A", strtotime($date_time));
```

[Check php.net for further details](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks great, except I will keep working to improve it as I would like it in 12 hour format. Thanks for the response though.